# navagator.onLine Wrong Value

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, internet-connection

I have a Cordova/Phonegap app and I am trying to determine if the device is online, so I have been using the `navigator.onLine` value.

I did not think this possible (because it seems very simple) that this value could be wrong.

When using this sample code (from the Mozilla Dev Center) and the iPhone is on Airplane Mode, it says that the device is "online":

```
if (navigator.onLine) {
  alert('online');
} else {
  alert('offline');
}
```

Is this not a good way to check if the device is online?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have come to the conclusion that `navigator.onLine` is not an effective way of determining if a device has access to the internet, as it sometimes means that the browser is fully loaded, or the computer has access to a Local Area Network fileserver.

If you are making an app that will run natively, or one that is running on a native platform like Cordova Phonegap, then it is better to use the device's built in API.

I ended up using the `network-information` API from Cordova: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-network-information/blob/master/doc/index.md